# How can I raise JSONDecodeError in Python

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, tflearn

Running:

Anaconda
TensorFlow 1.15 (for tflearn)
Mac 10.15.4
Python 3.6

Code:

```
import nltk
import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json
import pickle

from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

with open("Intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["Intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))

    labels = sorted(labels)

    training = []
    output = []

    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []

        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)

        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)

    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")


def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]
    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1

    return numpy.array(bag)


def chat():
    print("Start talking with the bot (type quit to stop)")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower == quit:
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        if results[results_index] > 0.7:
            for tg in data["Intents"]:
                if tg["tag"] == tag:
                    responses = tg["responses"]
            print(random.choice(responses))
        else:
            print("I didn't get that, try again.")


chat()
```

I worked out how to get TFlearn to work by uninstalling TF 2 and installing TF==1.15 but then I get this error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/summarizer.py:9: The name tf.summary.merge is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.merge instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py:25: The name tf.summary.FileWriter is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/collections.py:13: The name tf.GraphKeys is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/config.py:123: The name tf.get_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_collection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/config.py:129: The name tf.add_to_collection is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.add_to_collection instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/config.py:131: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = json.load(file)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/chatbot/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 12 column 5 (char 268)
```

I tried to use "utf=8" and that didn't work and so I don't really know what to do. I have no clue what's wrong. I'm a beginner.

Comment: please share json so that we will be able to see whats the problem with json. May be their is a missing bracket or missing comma inside the json.

Comment: JSON code is directly below the imports

Comment: Error is in the file "Intents.json". So I need to see that json.